# use express.bodyParser() and passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm working on a node server using express.js and passport.js. I'm in a condition, in which I don't want to use the `express.bodyParser()` before `app.use(passport.initialize())` and `app.use(passport.session())`. If I do a `app.use(express.bodyParser())` after the two passport middleware functions, they kind of mess up the req-stream and the bodyParser does not work anymore.

I want to use the bodyParser only in a few particular routes and not in the whole app. What I did to circumvent this error is the following (in every route I want to secure and use the bodyParser):

`app.post(route, express.json(), passport.initialize(), passport.session(), isAuthenticated, controller);`

But I think that's kind of nasty. Is there a solution to keep it DRY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### auth.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var express = require('express');
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  //...
}
module.exports = [
  express.json(),
  passport.initialize(),
  passport.session(),
  isAuthenticated
];
```

### somerouter.js

```
app.post(route, require('./auth'), controller);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sometimes it's just that easy. I forgot about the possibility to pass arrays as a route handler.